# ios Reloading UICollectionView after ViewWillAppear

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview

I am trying to manipulate UICollectionView.

**code in `viewDidLoad`:**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];

UINib * cellNib = [UINib nibWithNibName:@"NibCell" bundle:nil];

[collectionView registerNib:cellNib forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"CvCell"];

UICollectionViewFlowLayout * flowLayout = [[UICollectionViewFlowLayout alloc] init];

[flowLayout setItemSize:CGSizeMake(50, 100)];

[flowLayout setScrollDirection:UICollectionViewScrollDirectionHorizontal];

[collectionView setCollectionViewLayout:flowLayout];
}
```

In `viewWillAppear` I am calling a

> appearCallService

which downloads json and updates array. I am even calling reload method in viewWillAppear but still not working.

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {

[super viewWillAppear:YES];
hourlyTemperature = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
if ([Globals NetworkStatus]==YES) {
    [NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:@selector(appearCallService)     toTarget:self withObject:nil];
}

[collectionView reloadData];
}
```

`HourlyTemperature` is my array which is empty in `viewDidLoad` but still reloading in `viewWillAppear` doesn't work. Any suggestions?

Comment: Check ViewController life cycle your problem you can solve easily.

Comment: @HimanshuMoradiya It is not problem of view cycle. 
   Try to reload it in appearcallservice method